# PDF encryption on Google App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, pdf, encryption, bouncycastle

We're using Google App Engine (java flavour) and we want to encrypt our PDF's with the default PDF encryption using one (or two) passwords.

That's something a lot a libraries do quite fine, such as iText and Apache's [PDFBox](http://pdfbox.apache.org/).

But, in Google App Engine there are restrictions on what (java) libraries can be used. In our case, GAE doesn't allow the use of BouncyCastle encryption libraries.
We tried several PDF libraries (pdfbox, itext, pdfjet and more) but all need at least those libraries and fail to encrypt our in-memory byte[] of a PDF.

On GAE's blog, Google has accepted the request to [support BouncyCastle](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=1612), but there's no information when it might me available... Does anybody know more about that? I already put a question on the forum overthere, no reply yet.

There's a approach, but I need help or advise for that:

- SunJCE (and many others) security providers ARE allowed, so how much work would it be or is it a good idea to make a change in iText's sources (is opensource) and let it work with another provider? Is that something you would advice us to do? Or, is that weeks-and-weeks of work and custom algorithm-coding?
  What would be the steps? I don't know enough about Java encryption libraries to checkout if this is a valid route to follow.

Allowed providers according to a google forum:

- INFO: Found security provider SUN version 1.6
- INFO: Found security provider SunRsaSign version 1.5
- INFO: Found security provider SunJSSE version 1.6
- INFO: Found security provider SunJCE version 1.6
- INFO: Found security provider SunJGSS version 1.0
- INFO: Found security provider SunSASL version 1.5
- INFO: Found security provider XMLDSig version 1.0
- INFO: Found security provider SunPCSC version 1.6
- INFO: Found security provider SunMSCAPI version 1.6

Any advice?

Comment: Observation only: but there's some 60+ classes (a couple of package.*) imported from org.bouncycastle, referenced in 8 classes, none of which have obvious "non-bouncy" peers available to instantly replace them in the codebase. So, theoretically, you'd want to re-implement those 8 classes in terms of the JCE providers instead. At a glance, *if* the JCE providers give you the same crypto algorithms, the reimplementation *could* be pretty straightforward :-(

Comment: I'm curious why you want to encrypt PDFs in the first place. It's always seemed pretty pointless to me.